# Range query on partial composite columns

Tags: cassandra, composite, astyanax

I can't figure out how to make all the range queries i need using Astyanax.
I've tried what's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276457/how-to-query-on-multiple-composite-column-prefixes-with-astyanax) but it does not seem to work.

FYI I'm coming from the Hector world where i got this all working nicely and for reasons i won't explain, we decided to switch to Astyanax.

I have a column family described as follow. Note the "ReversedType" that allows us to have the latest TimeUUID first. It shouldn't impact the rest, at leat it never did with Hector:

```
ColumnFamily: mycf
      Key Validation Class: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)
      Default column value validator: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type
      Columns sorted by: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ReversedType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType))
```

And here's it's definition as an Astyanax CF:

```
public static final CF = new ColumnFamily<Rowkey, Column>(
    NAME,
    new AnnotatedCompositeSerializer<Rowkey>(Rowkey.class),
    new AnnotatedCompositeSerializer<Column>(Column.class),
    StringSerializer.get()
);

public static class Column {
    @Component(ordinal = 0)
    public String    colname        = null;
    @Component(ordinal = 1)
    public UUID        timeUUID    = null;
}

public static class Rowkey {
    @Component(ordinal = 0)
    public String    aid;
    @Component(ordinal = 1)
    public String    cid;
}
```

I use to be able to do a query using partial composites as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16796528/1872168). What i really need is to be able to do the following range queries:

```
# Range 1
# Should get the 10 first elements of the rowkey
colstart: null
colend: null
limit: 10

# Range 2
# Should get the 10 first elements of the rowkey
# that has as first part of the composite the string "mycol"
colstart: Column("mycol", null)
colend: Column("mycol", null)
limit: 10

# Range 3
# Should get the 10 first elements of the rowkey
# that has as first part of the composite the string "mycol"
# and with a timeuuid created with a timstamp between 'timestampStart' and 'timestampEnd'
colstart: Column("mycol", TimeUUID(timestampStart))
colend: Column("mycol", TimeUUID(timestampEnd))
limit: 10

# Range 4, not actually a range
# Should get the 1 column composed of "mycol" and existingTimeUUID
colstart: Column("mycol", existingTimeUUID)
colend: Column("mycol", existingTimeUUID)
limit: 10
```

Here's the 3 ways i've tried:

```
# Code 1
keyspace.prepareQuery(columnFamily)
    .getKey(rowkey)
    .withColumnRange(columnStart, columnEnd, false, 10)
    .execute()
    .getResult();

# Code 2
RangeBuilder rangeBuilder = new RangeBuilder()
    .setStart(columnStart, CF.getColumnSerializer())
    .setEnd(columnEnd, CF.getColumnSerializer())
    .setReversed(false)
    .setLimit(10);
keyspace.prepareQuery(columnFamily)
    .getKey(rowkey)
    .withColumnRange(rangeBuilder.build())
    .execute()
    .getResult();

# Code 3
CompositeRangeBuilder rangeBuilder = ((AnnotatedCompositeSerializer<Column>) colSerializer)
    .buildRange()
    .withPrefix(columnStart.colname)
    .greaterThanEquals(columnStart.timeUUID)
    .lessThanEquals(columnEnd.timeUUID)
    .limit(10);
keyspace.prepareQuery(columnFamily)
    .getKey(rowkey)
    .withColumnRange(rangeBuilder.build())
    .execute()
    .getResult();
```

Based on my Hector background, the composite i give (Annotated Classes) miss the EQUALITY parameter.
`Code 3` wouldn't do exactly what i need as the prefix applies to both start and end and those may be different if i wanted, for intance, to range query from (col1, timUUID1) to (col2, TimeUUID2).

I managed to make `Range 4` work with all three codes easely.

I managed to make `Range 1` work with all three codes by doing so:

- In `Code 1` i gave null as param for start and end
- In `Code 2` i avoided calling setStart and setEnd
- In `Code 3` i avoided calling withPrefix or any equality methode.

I managed to make `Range 2` work only with `Code 3`:

- I provided either `greaterThanEquals(columnStart.colname)` or `lessThanEquals(columnStart.colname)` and no other equality/prefix method

I did not manage to make `Range 3` at all.

Clearely, i would like to use only `Code 1` as I actually don't know the column family i will be querying. Here i'm just using an example with a composite column but it may not be composite or have more than 2 fields.

In hector it's really as easy as this and i would like some equivalent:

```
MultigetSliceQuery<K, C, V> q = HFactory.createMultigetSliceQuery(connection.getKeyspace(), this.getRowKeySerializer(), this.getColumnNameSerializer(), this.getColumnValueSerializer());
q.setColumnFamily(this.getCfName());
q.setKeys(keys)
q.setRange(colStart, colEnd, reversed, count);
q.execute();
```

With colStart and colEnd beeing of any type and if composite, allowing partial composites with an Equality defined on each component.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to do all i wanted using the above methods but i found a 4th one that even though it doesn't please me, works.

I'm using the `ByteBuffer` version of `withColumnRange` in `Code 1`. The start and end buffer are built using the actual Composite class as follows:

```java
public static <T> ByteBuffer toRangeStart(List<Object> list, boolean reversed) {
    return toRangeValue(list, reversed ? ComponentEquality.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL : ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
}

public static <T> ByteBuffer toRangeEnd(List<Object> list, boolean reversed) {
    return toRangeValue(list, reversed ? ComponentEquality.EQUAL : ComponentEquality.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL);
}

public static <T> ByteBuffer toRangeValue(List<Object> list, ComponentEquality eq) {
    // We use a real composite as we didn't find any other way to build those ranges
    Composite c = new Composite();

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        c.addComponent(list.get(i), SerializerTypeInferer.getSerializer(list.get(i)), ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
    }
    c.addComponent(list.get(i), SerializerTypeInferer.getSerializer(list.get(i)), eq);

    return c.serialize();
}
```